# Is it grammatically correct to say "can not be happened"?

Tags: grammaticality

I saw one of my friends giving thanks to her friends for a party on the occasion of new year celebration by giving a status update on facebook as "Thanks to all,without my friends the party can't be happened."

Comment: ...cannot *have* happened.

Comment: @TRomano as part of a conditional ("without my friends") would it not be more appropriate as "...could not have happened"?

Comment: @RichF: True, "couldn't have happened without..."  would be idiomatic in the "if it were'n for my friends, there would have been no party" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Much better would have been:

- Thanks to all; without my friends the party could not have happened.

*Can* and *be* can work together, but usually in regards to location. For example, "I can be there."  In regards to the question, something "can happen", or it "was happening", but I cannot think of any form of *can be happen* which would flow right.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a past action, *can* isn't the adequate verb for that ocassion, *can't* could work well if the sentence were:

> Thanks to all my friends, the party can't happen without you.

However, it would imply to say that the party hasn't started yet, *i,e*,  it will still start, or it would be a habitual action, which implies to say that without friends, parties aren't fun.

If you wanted to say that the party wouldn't have been fun or wouldn't have happened without your friends, then you should have used *could* or *would* -

> Thanks to all, without my friends that party couldn't have happened
>
> Thanks to all, without my friends that party wouldn't have happened

Remember that you can also change the "*without my friends*" placement, by putting it at the end of the statement would make it sound better